# Finding a minimum spanning tree on a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

What algorithm can I use to find a minimum spanning tree on a directed graph? I tried using a modification of Prim's algorithm, but wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: What steps do you need to take to calculate this value?

Comment: Does Kruskal's count as a modified Prim's?

Comment: I was able to solve it. thank you!

Comment: MST for a directed graph is a different problem. It is the Minimum Cost Arborescence Problem.

Answer (score 39):

The equivalent of a minimum spanning tree in a directed graph is called an *optimum branching* or a *minimum-cost arborescence*. The classical algorithm for solving this problem is the [Chu-Liu/Edmonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm) algorithm. There have been several optimized implementations of this algorithm over the years using better data structures; the best one that I know of uses a Fibonacci heap and runs in time O(m + n log n) and is due to [Galil et al.](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~simhaweb/champalg/mst/papers/GabowMST.pdf)

Hope this helps!

Comment: anyone happen to know of an implementation of this? I've found limited implementations of the Chu-Liu/Edmonds algorithm, but nothing for the algorithm by Galil et al.