# Boost Graph: with vertices as integral type, how to provide arguments to Edmund's arborescence algorithm that requires vertex iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, graph, boost-graph

I am trying to solve the problem of finding an arborescence in a directed graph. This functionality is [not provided directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836334/boost-graph-library-minimum-spanning-tree-of-a-directed-graph) by the boost graph library. However, an implementation is available [here](https://github.com/atofigh/edmonds-alg) that builds on boost graph library.

The interface provided by the author available [here](https://github.com/atofigh/edmonds-alg/blob/master/src/edmonds_optimum_branching.hpp) specifies the following function signature:

```
void
edmonds_optimum_branching(TEdgeListGraph &g,
                          TVertexIndexMap index,
                          TWeightMap weight,
                          TInputIterator roots_begin,
                          TInputIterator roots_end,
                          TOutputIterator out);
```

The author's description of `roots_begin` and `roots_end` is:

> roots_begin and roots_end are iterators over vertices of g. Any
> vertices in this range are guaranteed to be roots in the final
> branching. This range may of course be empty, in which case
> appropriate roots are found by the algorithm.

An example is provided by the author [here](https://github.com/atofigh/edmonds-alg/blob/master/doc/examples/sparse-example.cpp) and it calls the algorithm thus:

```
edmonds_optimum_branching<true, false, false>(G,
                                                  vertex_indices,
                                                  weights,
                                                  static_cast<Vertex *>(0), //Is this conversion to an empty iterator  ?
                                                  static_cast<Vertex *>(0),// or is this conversion to an iterator pointing to vertex 0, the first node?
                                                  std::back_inserter(branching));
```

If I understand correctly, `roots_begin` and `roots_end` are both NULL (?) and hence the problem is solved with no prespecified roots.

What would change suppose I have a graph with 50 vertices, and I want vertex 5 to serve as the root node?

Should the two arguments be:

```
edmonds_optimum_branching<true, false, false>(G,
                                                  vertex_indices,
                                                  weights,
                                                  static_cast<Vertex *>(5),
                                                  static_cast<Vertex *>(6)
                                                  std::back_inserter(branching));
```

This, however, shows a compile time error over the `static_cast` as an invalid type conversion of an int.

Should the two argument just be:

```
edmonds_optimum_branching<true, false, false>(G,
                                                  vertex_indices,
                                                  weights,
                                                  5,
                                                  6,
                                                  std::back_inserter(branching));
```

This, however, does not compile either with the error:

```
../include/edmonds_optimum_branching_impl.hpp:247:41: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
  247 |                 is_specified_root[index[*roots_begin]] = true;
```

I posted the question on the author's github page also, but it does not seem to be frequently visited by the author.

Comment: Ah...solved it thus: `std::vector<int> roots = {5};` Then call the algorithm with respective parameters being `...,roots.begin(), roots.end(),...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are generalizations of pointers. Pointers are iterators, but more complicated things like whatever `std::vector<T>::begin` and `std::vector<T>::return` return and whatever `std::back_inserter` constructs are also iterators. The key thing about them that you appear to be missing is that if `it` is an iterator, then the value associated with it is accessed as `*it`, not `it`. Because you cannot dereference an `int`, that is not a valid iterator.

You need to do exactly what the documentation says: provide iterators that define a range that contains `5`. Because pointers are iterators, you could do

```cpp
int root = 5;
edmonds_optimum_branching<true, false, false>(
    G, vertex_indices, weights,
    &root, &root + 1, // *&root = 5, std::next(&root) = &root + 1, so this range produces 5 and then ends
    std::back_inserter(branching))
```

The example uses the fact that pointers are iterators to pass `nullptr` and `nullptr` as defining an empty range. Typewise, `nullptr` is a pointer and so all the uses of `*it` in `edmonds_optimum_branching` would compile, but when actually executing the begin and end iterators would be found equal and thus no access would be made.

Comment: Thanks. As you were answering, I tried another way, which seemed to compile. I have added that to my question as a comment. Your approach seems fine as well.