# Remove transitive edges in graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, nodes, breadth-first-search

I have a graph

[image]

Since I can go from 1 to 2 to 3 (i.e. from 1 to 3 through 2), the edge from 1 to 3 is unnecessary.

Therefore, I want to remove the edge directly between 1 and 3.

How would I do this? I guess I should do breadth-first search to decide where I can go from 1.

So if I have all my nodes and edges

```
nodes = [1, 2, 3]
edges = [
  {source: 1, target: 2},
  {source: 1, target: 3},
  {source: 2, target: 3}
]
```

I want to remove

```
  {source: 1, target: 3},
```

since it is unnecessary because of transitivity, but how could I determine whether I should remove

```
  {source: 1, target: 3},
```

instead of

```
  {source: 2, target: 3}
```

?

Comment: Minimum spanning tree of a digraph: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991823/finding-a-minimum-spanning-tree-on-a-directed-graph

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the transitive reduction of the graph, [this article should help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction).

Comment: I have already implemented a BFS. Would it be possible to use it for this?

Comment: BFS can help you achieving the solution, but you will need more than that.